# Tmux seems to be taking some input (backspace, enter) literally. How can I stop this?

Tags: tmux

I've got debian and when I'm in tmux, sometimes my input is taken literally. (FWIW I ssh into this computer.)

For instance, I was earlier doing:

```
sudo apt-get remove ftp
```

And when It would ask for y/n, I could input the letters just fine. But when I hit enter, I would get "^M^ instead. When I hit delete, I got "^?" instead.

When I closed tmux, everything worked just fine, and I could uninstall ftp.

Does anyone know why this is / how to fix it?

EDIT: This also happens when I am running code I've written in c++ and use std::cin. In tmux, the ^M key is displayed in the terminal, but when I'm not in tmux, the code runs as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *line discipline* of the pseudo-terminal within `tmux` has its *special characters* and *input flags* set differently to the line discipline of whatever terminal you are attaching to `tmux`.

Run the command

```
stty -a
```

on both terminals, and note the difference(s).  Adjust with the `stty` command according to taste.  A "sane" starting point is often

```
stty sane
```

Of course, the manual for `stty` is your friend.  ☺

Comment: My output in tmux and in normal terminal is the same when I do "stty -a" though the problem still persists. Any ideas?

Thank you very much for the help, though!

EDIT: stty sane worked, but it keeps un-doing itself. I'll have to look and see if I messed up my .bashrc or some other config. THANK YOU!